# First countable not Lindelöf space

Tags: general-topology

It is well known that any second-countable space is a Lindelöf space, but not conversely (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space)). Moreover, any second-countable space is, clearly, first-countable.

> **Question.** Does there exist a first countable space with is not Lindelöf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrete topology provides an example on any non-countable set $X$.

It is clearly first-countable since $\{x\}$ is a local basis for any point $x$.

The open cover $\{ \{x\} | x\in X\}$ has no countable subcover.

Comment: More generally: any non-separabel metric space... in a metric space, Lindeløf implies separable, but first countable is true for any metric space.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=First%20Countable%2B%7ELindelof) for such questions. Except for the already mentioned uncountable discrete space, we get metric examples as the plane in the post-office metric and the radial metric. The river metric also works, but is not in the database. More exotic ones include the Sorgenfrey plane, the ordinal $\omega_1$ and the long line..